# SharePoint Online / O365: Allow users to create *only* personal views

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-views

Is there a permission or other setting that would allow users to create personal views in a library/list where they are contributors but NOT public views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific permission called Manage Personal Views  under Personal Permissions or simply if you provide users with Contribute, edit or Full control, thy can create and manage personal views.

[image: Manage Personal Views]

I guess you need to be a site collection admin to create a permssion level. Add this specific permission to that permission level and provide users with access to that permission level.

Comment: Hmm, I'll look at that. I'm a site collection level admin. Right now it seems like anyone can create personal & public views and I just want to limit creation of public ones. Thanks!

Comment: Found this, https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4b2165a6-3811-4722-a316-22a832ffe784/prevent-sharepoint-librarians-from-creating-public-views?forum=sharepointadminprevious . Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I think we're on to something. I'll come back with details if I end up with something funky/cool.